# Rails messing up with my Postgres TIME columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am using postgres TIME type to represent a branch office opening hour.

I am aware Rails does not handle the TIME column alone, initializing the values with a default date: 01 Jan 2000.

I have no problem with that except for the fact that my user timezone is -03, so when the user picks a time, let's say 22:00:00, Rails actually changes it to 01:00:00 and stores that value instead. Then, when I load it from the db it might even load a different date (the day before or after 01 Jan, which is a headache when I am comparing times).

How can I tell Rails to not change the original input to the server timezone? Or is there any other better workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Rails always have TZ associated with times, it also stores everything in utc in DB. Out of the box, it does correct encoding/decoding. My assumption is - you have done your own decoding when you retrieve values from the DB. In this case, what you can do is to write helper like this:

```rb
def strip_tz(time)
  Time.new(time.year, time.month, time.day, time.hour, time.min, time.sec, "+00:00")
end
```

And use it when you pass time value to the model creation.